# Can CDI scan a configured folder at injection time for beans? (hot deployment)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a Java EE 6 Web application running on Apache TomEE.

My application defines a few interfaces A, B and C. I have multiple .jar files containing implementations to these interfaces. Whenever a client makes a certain request, my web application uses CDI to scan for these implementations and injects whatever implementation is needed.

However, I do not want to configure all these implementation .jar files by name in advance. I would love to just configure a folder location in which all these implementation .jar files reside, and let CDI do the discovery. **I want CDI to re-scan this folder at every injection, so I can add and remove .jar files without restarting my web application.**

Using Tomcat's VirtualWebappLoader or TomEE (1.6.0)'s jars.txt, I am able to successfully set such a folder and have CDI inject .jar beans that were available at application startup. However,

- I haven't been able to inject .jar beans that were not available at app startup but added later by me
- My web app keeps using injected beans of which I have removed the .jar completely

**Will I ever be able to achieve such "hot deployment" with CDI?
If not, can you help me understand why?**

Comment: John Ament has it right. May I ask what your functional requirement is? VirtualWebappLoader is not recommended for production and for development it seems simple enough to restart instead?

Comment: The webapp functions as a framework. Developers of client applications can drop components in this pre-defined folder and ask the webapp to process some data using the beans they just 'installed'. As the webapp would serve multiple developers of client apps at the same time, a restart is kind of said. I understand it's not recommended for production, I am mainly researching CDI capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  CDI scans at deployment time for files.